# How to vectorise a list of matrix vector multiplications using pytorch/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, pytorch, tensor

For example, I have a list of `N` `B x H` tensor(i.e. a `N x B x H` tensor) and a list of `N` vectors (i.e. `N x B` tensor). And I want multiply each `B x H` tensor in the list with corresponding `B` dimensional tensor, resulting a `N x H` tensor.

I know how to use a single `for-loop` with PyTorch to implement the computation, but is there any vectorised implantation? (i.e. no `for-loop`, just using PyTorch/numpy operations)

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]?

Comment: Seconded. I have an idea in my head of what you're trying but it would be much more reassuring if I have some defined input and output to test against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this with [`torch.bmm()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.bmm) and some [`torch.squeeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.squeeze)/[`torch.unsqueeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze).

I am personally rather fond of the more generic[`torch.einsum()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.einsum) (which I find more readable):

```python
import torch
import numpy as np

A = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]],
                               [[4, 40, 400], [5, 50, 500], [6, 60, 600]]]))
B = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[ 1,  2,  3],
                               [-1, -2, -3]]))

AB = torch.einsum("nbh,nb->nh", (A, B))
print(AB)
# tensor([[   14,   140,  1400],
#         [  -32,  -320, -3200]])
```